# Trying to add lines between each button

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am working on a settings screen design for this startup and am very new to react native. I am an intern, but I am trying to add lines between each button. I'll attach a screenshot of what it should kind of look like, but I just am lost with no matter how much I look up, I can't find something that will work for me.

So far what I did was:

```
<View className="w-full mt-2 mb-7 flex-row">
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate(RouteName.home)} className="flex flex-row items-center space-x-3 w-24">
            <Ionicons name='person-sharp' size={24} color="grey"></Ionicons>
            <Text>Profile</Text>
            <AntDesign name='right' size={24} color='#7A7A7A' style={{position: 'absolute', right: 0}}></AntDesign>
          </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

I dont have a specific stylesheet connected to it other than the inline one.

I attached a picture of what it should look like, but I am mainly struggling on the line between each button.

[image: What I was able to do]

[image: What it should look like]

Comment: Please add the image of what you've done so far and/or what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @RohitAggarwal Sorry! I thought I did, the first pic is what I was able to do, the second pic is what it should look like.

Comment: Just add a border bottom to your parent view